# Rendering speed and image quality with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, image, performance, opengl-es

I just noticed that if I display a moving picture at 30fps instead of 60fps, the image seems to lose quality. I'm not talking about the movement beeing less smooth which is normal, but the picture in itself seems to be more pixelised.

Do you have any idea why and maybe an idea to fix it?

Comment: I doubt that the picture itself is different. You could take screenshots to convince yourself. I suspect that it's a visual effect that makes the aliasing less noticeable if you have a smoother animation. It intuitively kind of makes sense: If the same image is visible for only half the time, it's going to be more difficult to pick up the aliasing. It's vaguely related to temporal anti-aliasing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasing), where you need more blurring if the frame rate is lower at the same animation speed.

Comment: Well thanks, very interresting !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I was using :

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

which is more "pixel-art" than below which is more smooth :

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

But as Peter O. said, there is a link with temporal anti aliasing too :

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasing